# Probability counting question

Tags: probability

Conceptually it hasn't properly 'clicked' for:

Sampling without replacement without ordering= nCk.

For example i understand sampling without replacement but with ordering is: n(n-1)...(n-k+1) because these are the 'number of choices' at each stage of the ordering, how can i think of the above in a similar way?

Thanks

Comment: You select uniformly at random one of the $k$-element subsets (instead of $k$-tuples) of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. There are that many of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know that sampling without replacement gives $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$ ordered $k$-tuples. If you now ignore order, how many $k$-tuples are the same as a given $k$-tuple (remember that all the elements in the $k$-tuple are distinct)? Clearly there are $k!$ of them. So the number of unordered $k$-tuples sampled without replacement is
$$ \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdot(n-k+1)\cdot (n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!}
      = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \dbinom{n}{k}.$$

Comment: Ah ye thanks this is how i'll think about it :)